# Is it possible to do randomForest classification on a database that I pull from SQLite?

Tags: r, sqlite, random-forest

new here so apologies for errors.

I am working with a massive set of data (16GB) and trying to create a randomForest classification model using R in RStudio. I can't use read.csv to import the data into a data frame because my computer can't handle it (or it's not feasible, I believe that both are probably true in some sense). To remedy my issue, I created a new SQLite database with the tables of data that I want to try and load into R, and have no problem getting access to the data when I use dplyr to connect to my SQLite database. However, when I attempt to fit a randomForest model using the data, it throws an error, saying that "data (x) has 0 rows," which I believe is due to the fact that nrow() won't work with a table pulled from SQLite. Can anyone tell me what my options are to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

tl;dr: nrow() doesn't work on SQLite databases in R, so randomForest classification doesn't work. Help!

Edit #1: @hamagaust suggested I post code that I have, and what I have tried. Here is the code I am working with:

```
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "MyData.db")
X_train_all <- tbl(con, "X_train_all") 
X_test_all <- tbl(con, "X_test_all")
head(X_train_all) # Returns the table I see in SQLite, as in I know the data is correct. 
nrow(X_train_all) # Returns NA

classifier <- randomForest(X_train_all, Y_train_all, ntree = 100) # Throws error (Y_train_all isn't the problem, that is a small .txt file I was able to import easily.
```

For further background, I am taking over a project and attempting to translate what has been done already in Python into R, with X_train_all, X_test_all, y_train_all, y_test_all having already been created and used to successfully implement a randomForest model in python.

Edit #2: Apologies, my data is in a table in R, not a data frame.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. In the order to enhance the chances of getting useful answers, it is a good practice to
(I) include the code you have tried already;
(ii) include all code, error messages, and data (`dput() or `str()`) in the text (formated as code or citation), not as an image. 
And (iii) detail all the objectives, problems, packages, and any attempts to solve the problem.
In your specific case, I believe you are dealing with some problem in acquiring the data. Are you able to verify the structure and the class of the data? And include here to start?

Comment: @hamagust thank you for your comment! Hopefully my edits provide some more information on the issue. The class of X_train_all is [1] "tbl_SQLiteConnection", "tbl_dbi", "tbl_sql", "tbl_lazy", [5] "tbl" , and I am working with a tbl. I realize now that I said data frame in my original post, which is incorrect.

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your question, but there's no way that the `randomForest` package will work with data that big - I would recommend switching your random forest package to `ranger` or `Rborist` which are optimised for large datasets.